# Margin of Error Discrepancy (manual and online calculator)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

A total of 498 participants responded to a survey questionnaire. I want to be ascertain that the sample size of 498 reflects the opinions of the true population (say 1,000,000).

I used an **online calculator** that shows that the margin of error is 4%
population size: 1000,000
confidence level (%): 95
Your sample size: 498

The margin of error is **4%** (online calculator)

**Manual Calculation:**
Group A: 123, Group B: 70, Group C:37, Group D:40, Group E:74, Group F:15, Group G:15, Group H:15, Group I:28, Group J:81

Count, N:   10
Sum, Σx:    498
Mean, x̄:   49.8
Variance, s2:   1299.2888888889
std deviation, s =  √1299.2888888889
s =  36.04565006889

Standard Error, sx̄ = s / √N
=  36/ √10
=11.39863539591

Margin of Error = critical value x Standard Error
= 1.96 x 11.39863539591
= 22.341

Please advise why the margin of error (using manual calculation) results in 22.341

Comment: Please tell us what you think a "margin of error" might mean with ten groups.  What exactly are you trying to estimate here??

Comment: Referring to the online calculator at https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/margin-of-error-calculator/ it shows that the margin of error is 4% based on the total sample size of 498 participants. In the above calculation, N=10; Does N (total number of values) need to be 498? If N=498, then Standard Error, sx̄ = s / √N = 36.04565006889/ √498 =1.61524; Margin of Error is 1.96 x 1.61524 = 3.17 >>>> which is close to 4% (with a 95% confidence interval of critical value 1.96). Is that correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it impossible to tell what you're doing.  You need to explain what your groups mean and what you are trying to learn from this survey.

Comment: Sorry, I was not explicit enough. We surveyed participants from the gaming sector comprising developers, designers, narrators, programmers, etc. These are the groups. The goal is to show that the sample size of 498 (by combining all the groups) reflects the true population of the gaming industry (100,000+). I guess I was confused above in my preliminary expose about denoting N. I illustrated N = 10 (number of groups) rather than N=498 (total sample size)

Comment: We can also say that if the margin of error is small, the chosen sample represents
the opinions of the true population with more confidence.

Comment: No amount of analysis of the sample itself will answer that question.  The sample will reflect the gaming industry if it was rigorously obtained with randomization.  Otherwise, it potentially could be compared to other samples or data about the industry as a check--but that requires other data.  What you can do is compute margins of error for each group *assuming* it is random.  The MoEs (reflecting 95% confidence) will be approximately 21% for the small groups.

Comment: Please advise if the above is logical and makes sense, as to what I am trying to showcase. Thanks

Comment: I have already provided that opinion.